# Are logical truths a subset of facts which in turn is a subset of possible truths?

Tags: logic, knowledge

Are logical truths (those that are true in all possible interpretations) a subset of facts (known via observation in our reality)? Are facts a subset of possible truths(satisfiable)? Where do axioms fit in? Or, are logical truths separate and unrelated to facts/observable truths?

Comment: Most facts are not necessary while logical truths if they exist are inevitable and a priori, then how can logical truths be a subset of facts, but it could be said to be reflecting those necessary facts, but not via observation in our reality otherwise deductive logic becomes inductive and uncertain (remember there's a famous Hume's problem of induction even for valid observations?)...